# Can't get PayPal Encrypted Website Payments to work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I am having problems getting PayPal Encrypted Website payments to work on a Rails site.

I am getting two different error messages when posting to the PayPal URL - on my staging site, which uses the sandbox, I am getting:

> The certificate has been removed. Please use a valid certificate.

Whereas on the production site, I get:

> We were unable to decrypt the certificate id.

As far as I can tell they are set up identically, except that one uses the PayPal Sandbox public key, and the other uses the normal PayPal public key. I must be overlooking some detail but I have banging my head against this for a couple of days now.

I used the following commands to generate public and private keys:

```
openssl genrsa -out app_key.pem 1024

openssl req -new -key app_key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out app_cert.pem
```

Then I uploaded `app_cert.pem` to PayPal and put my cert ID into a file like this:

```
development:
  user: seller_1259814545_biz@somedomain.com
  action_url: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr 
  paypal_cert_file: certs/paypal_sandbox_cert.pem
  app_cert_file: certs/app_cert.pem
  app_key_file: certs/app_key.pem
  cert_id: CBDFN7JXBM2ZQ
  secret: dfasdkjh3453

test:
  user: seller_1259814545_biz@somedomain.com
  action_url: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr 
  paypal_cert_file: certs/paypal_sandbox_cert.pem
  app_cert_file: certs/app_cert.pem
  app_key_file: certs/app_key.pem
  cert_id: CBDFN7JXBM2ZQ
  secret: dfasdkjh3453

staging:
  user: seller_1259814545_biz@somedomain.com
  action_url: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr 
  paypal_cert_file: certs/paypal_sandbox_cert.pem
  app_cert_file: certs/app_cert.pem
  app_key_file: certs/app_key.pem
  cert_id: CBDFN7JXBM2ZQ
  secret: dfasdkjh3453

production:
  user: business@somedomain.com
  action_url: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr 
  paypal_cert_file: certs/paypal_cert.pem
  app_cert_file: certs/app_cert.pem
  app_key_file: certs/app_key.pem
  cert_id: QG2TTZZM9DUH6
  secret: dfasdkjh3453
```

Then I use the following code in my Cart model to encrypt the data:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy

  PAYPAL_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/#{PAYPAL_CONFIG[:paypal_cert_file]}")
  APP_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/#{PAYPAL_CONFIG[:app_cert_file]}")
  APP_KEY_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/#{PAYPAL_CONFIG[:app_key_file]}")

  ...

  def paypal_data(return_url, notify_url)
    values = {
      :business => PAYPAL_CONFIG[:user],
      :cert_id => PAYPAL_CONFIG[:cert_id],
      :custom => PAYPAL_CONFIG[:secret],
      :cmd => '_cart',
      :upload => 1,
      :return => return_url,
      :notify_url => notify_url,
      :invoice => id,
      :currency_code => 'AUD'
    }
    line_items.each_with_index do |item, i|
      values.merge!({
        "amount_#{i+1}" => "%.2f" % item.unit_price_ex_gst,
        "tax_#{i+1}" => "%.2f" % item.unit_gst,
        "item_name_#{i+1}" => item.product.full_name,
        "item_number_#{i+1}" => item.id,
        "quantity_#{i+1}" => item.quantity
      })
    end
    encrypt_for_paypal(values)
  end

  def encrypt_for_paypal(values)
    signed = OpenSSL::PKCS7::sign(OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(APP_CERT_PEM), 
      OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(APP_KEY_PEM, ''), 
      values.map { |key, value| "#{key}=#{value}" }.join("\n"), [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
    OpenSSL::PKCS7::encrypt([OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(PAYPAL_CERT_PEM)], 
      signed.to_der, 
      OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("DES3"), 
      OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY).to_s.gsub("\n", '')
  end
end
```

Then I use the following code in the view:

```
- form_tag PAYPAL_CONFIG[:action_url] do
  %div
    = hidden_field_tag :cmd, '_s-xclick'
    = hidden_field_tag :encrypted, cart.paypal_data(thanks_payments_url, payments_url)
    = image_submit_tag 'paypal-checkout.gif', :alt => 'Check out with PayPal: The safer, easier way to pay'
```

There don't seem to be any newlines or other characters in the output which I am aware can stuff up the process.

I have checked and double-checked that I am using all the right certificates and certificate ids, and that what has been uploaded to PayPal matches what is in my `certs` directory.

I have completely run out of ideas to try. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the raw HTML from PayPal *exactly* as it was? Make sure there are no extra new lines.

Comment: I didn't copy any HTML from PayPal. This is a custom integration.

Comment: It's working on my development machine, but not on the server. Deployed code base is at the same revision. Certificates are checked into source control and deployed with the code base.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working in staging and production now.

The only thing I can think of is that there was some sort of problem or delay with PayPal and the certificates on their side.

Comment: PayPal is all over the place at the moment, I think they are deploying a new version of their checkout page. They seem to have switched back and forward between the new and old version a few times.